# too late to get mavericks?

Tags: macos

I'm on an older imac on SnowLeopard and didn't upgrade as was happy with the OS and heard there were bugs with Lion etc.

I didn't realise Mavericks was going to disappear from the app store. I'm not sure if many of my apps like CS5 are going to be compatible with Yosemite, and I only have 4GB of RAM.

Is there any way to get mavericks now? Or am I too late?

Comment: Is your mac capable of handling Mavericks?
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204319

Answer (score 1):

OS X Mavericks is not legally available (via the Mac App Store) anymore. Sharing it is not allowed.

Edit: just remembered that I needed it too a could of months ago and I called Apple. They said 'it might be available in the future'.

Answer (score -1):

It is too late to download Mavericks from the Mac App Store, but if you can find someone you know that has purchased Mavericks in the App Store they can still download it. If not, I'm sure you would be able to find a copy online somewhere from a less legitimate source.

Comment: You may want to check the OS X license before you go down that route.

Answer (score -1):

Is this the file you need? I still have it from when I upgraded from Mt Lion. Also have Mt Lion installer.
[image]

Comment: It is against the license agreement to share software like this. We do not condone piracy or breaking the license agreement.

Comment: @tubedogg, can you clarify? Obviously I'm against piracy but as far as I know, Mavericks is / was free. Does it break any license agreements if for example I downloaded Mavericks when it was available, I copied the 5GB *.app installer to my external pendrive, HDD etc. to store it for myself and months later I would like to share this *.app file with my wife / friend / anybody? It makes no sense. Please explain that. BTW - please take a look here: http://bit.ly/1GFdcMl This is my tutorial. See the first attached screenshot. Does it mean that I cannot share Install OS X Mavericks.app?

Comment: The cost of legitimately acquiring software has no correlation to whether distribution is allowed in the license agreement. Apple does not allow distribution of their software, therefore sharing it with anyone is not allowed (with the exception of their previously-offered family packs, and even then it's restricted to family members in [I believe] the same household). It may "make[] no sense" to you but it is the license agreement to which you agreed when you downloaded the software. @slick