# Where can I purchase Mavericks?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My husband would like to install OS X Mavericks, not Yosemite. He's using Snow Leopard right now on his MacBook Pro (early 2008). How could he do that?

Comment: [too late to get mavericks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/151617/8546) (2014-10-19)

Comment: Towards another answer: [Feedback to Apple to request OS X Mavericks in the Apple Store](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=20984899#post20984899)

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities here as far as I'm aware:

1. Take the Mac to an Apple store where they *may* be willing to install Mavericks for you.
2. Find someone who is running Mavericks, or who has upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite, and who is willing to help you. They will be able to download the Mavericks installer from their previous purchases in the App Store, and then they can pass the installer on to you via network or USB stick.